# Script to delete all non-system objects in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Does anyone have a script that will delete all non-system tables/procs/views from a database?

I created some views, procs and tables which I need to clean up and doing them individually is too cumbersome.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could always query your system catalog views and have it generate the necessary DROP statements:

```
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' + pr.NAME +']'
FROM sys.procedures pr
WHERE pr.is_ms_shipped = 0

UNION

SELECT 'DROP VIEW [' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' + v.NAME + ']'
FROM sys.views v
WHERE v.is_ms_shipped = 0

UNION

SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_ID) + '] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + fk.name 
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0

UNION

SELECT 'DROP TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' + t.NAME + ']'
FROM sys.tables t
WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0
```

This will generate a long list of `DROP .....` statements, just copy & paste those into a new SSMS window and execute them.

Comment: You will need to drop all foreign key constraints before dropping the tables (since they are dropped in random order).

Comment: Unfortunately that won't include schema names. This should work for tables: SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' + '['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'

Comment: @Jedidja: yes, you're right - I updated my response to include that - thanks!

Comment: I also needed synonymns, queues, and functions: select 'DROP QUEUE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' + sq.NAME +']'
FROM sys.service_queues sq
WHERE sq.is_ms_shipped = 0

UNION

SELECT 'DROP FUNCTION [' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' + fn.NAME +']'
FROM sys.objects fn
WHERE fn.is_ms_shipped = 0 and fn.type in ('FN','IF','TF')

UNION

SELECT 'DROP SYNONYM [' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].[' + sy.NAME +']'
FROM sys.synonyms  sy
WHERE sy.is_ms_shipped = 0

Answer (score 11):

Wouldn't it be easier to drop/recreate the database?

```
DROP DATABASE yourdbname
CREATE DATABASE yourdbname
```

Comment: +1 for SQL-Server drop/recreate is fast. For Oracle databases I use indeed such scripts as it takes less time.

Comment: Except if you have accidentally created tables in the master database :) I'm guessing the original poster might have done this, hence the question about "non-system" objects.